# What codes do I have to implement to install the UTMStack Server?

Tags: windows, installation, encoding

I want to install UTMStack Server in Windows OS; however, I don't know what codes to use.
Can anybody here help me with some instructions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

At this time UTMStack only runs on Ubuntu Server and has a fully featured community edition that does not require any license or codes.

You can find installation instructions here: https://github.com/AtlasInsideCorp/UTMStackInstaller

And a video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dM9dC9HNXUs&feature=youtu.be